# XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://domain.com:8080/socket.io/1/?t=1416289828054 No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present

Tags: sockets, webrtc, licode

I am creating an application using Licode, this is a video conference application in which i have created a room though the XMLHttpRequest call but no able to make connection using XMLHttpRequest following error occurs.

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://domain.com:8080/socket.io/1/?t=1416289828054. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://domain.com:3001' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

I am facing this issue even i have implemented following code on server

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    "use strict";
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://'+req.headers.host+':8000');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'origin, content-type');
    if (req.method == 'OPTIONS') {
        res.send(200);
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like I had the similar issue (everything works fine util I deployed it on server). First of all check all firewalls and access to socket port from your computer. In my case, the issue was with F5, see [here](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/issues/1347).

Note:

> Because F5 will default protocol identified as http, so we need
>   disable the http protocol,like this when HTTP_REQUEST {  if {
>   ([HTTP::uri] starts_with "/socket.io") } { HTTP::disable }  }

Hope, I helped you ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i already solved the issue this is the issue with port that is already being used by tomcat.